# Executor Timeout errors in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to run a job that does this:

1. Takes in a dataframe
2. Converts it to rdd
3. Performs a bunch of operations
4. Reduce by key + union of rdds
5. Convert it back to dataframe
6. Save it to s3

I have tried using dataframes, but in that case, I end up with OOM errors due to size of some of the rows exceeding 2GBs.

During the job run, when I try to write the dataframe out as a parquet, my run fails with this error:

```
/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.pyc in parquet(self, path, mode, partitionBy, compression)
    837             self.partitionBy(partitionBy)
    838         self._set_opts(compression=compression)
--> 839         self._jwrite.parquet(path)
    840 
    841     @since(1.6)

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.pyc in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o589402.parquet.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:710)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:710)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:240)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:710)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:292)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:235)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:600)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 29 in stage 40.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 29.3 in stage 40.0 (TID 3394, 10.46.190.16, executor 26): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 26 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Executor heartbeat timed out after 173204 ms
Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2355)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2343)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2342)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2342)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1096)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1096)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1096)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2574)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2522)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2510)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:893)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2243)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:167)
    ... 34 more
```

I am trying to figure out what might be causing this failure? It seems like it's due to one of the executors not responding with a heartbeat, but I am surprised since the dataframe should not be that big to begin with. Any help is greatly appreciated.

If my dataframe is small, I have no trouble writing it to s3

Comment: It could be a lot of things, my first guess is to look at the default config of the cluster, some default config could be aborting nodes of your job. About the OOM problems with using dataframe, you can avoid them by passing the  argument `spark.driver.memory` into the spark2-submit command

Comment: Also I dont know which version of spark you are using, but you can look at the params you can pass here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/configuration.html
this is for version `2.1`